# magento 2 error while placing order from admin

Tags: magento2, place-order

While placing order from admin getting constraint violation error.

***when I printed exception i am getting below error string,***

```
Order saving error: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation:
1062 Duplicate entry '0' for key 'PRIMARY', query was: INSERT INTO
`sales_order_grid` (`last_admin_edit`) VALUES (?)
```

Any idea what is the cause?

Answer (score 0):

Error causing due to custom module attribute "last_admin_edit" added in sales_order_grid table.
Made changes in custom module code.